# mysql contains certain strings from another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:
first table contains a list of strings
second table contains a name and a description

I want to get in mysql a list of all the strings of the first table that are contained in the description of a particular line of the second table.

For example:
FirstTable(String):

```
sam
thierry
chris
```

SecondTable (name | description):

```
first | I am sam and I am the brother of Chris
second | I am thierry
```

I want to get a list that contains:

```
sam
chris
```

If I select the first line of the secondTable.

Is that possible?

Comment: Are you aware of the [LOCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Query

```
SELECT FirstTable.* FROM FirstTable, SecondTable 
WHERE LOCATE(FirstTable.`String`, SecondTable.`description`) > 0
AND name='first';
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17971/2)